# How to calculate the boiling point of a solid substance?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, boiling-point, melting-point

Say that I have a solid substance; I know its density, mass, volume, melting point, specific heat, the pressure which it is under, and nothing else. (for now.)

How do I find the heat at which it boils? (So it goes solid -> liquid -> gas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't...it must be found experimentally (it has) P.S Even if you know the BP at 1 atm, you can never calculate the real boiling point at any given BP, you may come close

Comment: As in, it cannot be calculated using the information at hand, or it must be found experimentally in any case? If it's the former, what other information do I need in order to find at least an approximation of the boiling point?

Comment: It cannot be calculated using the information at hand, not even approximately. As to what other information may help... well, you may ask about the enthalpy and entropy of vaporization, but then why not ask about the boiling point itself.